# Lock scrolling when element is at top of window, scroll through Bootstrap carousel, then continue scrolling down the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website and the idea is as once each of the three sections makes contact with the top of the window, the entire page scrolling locks allowing the user to scroll through Bootstrap Carousel slides using the mousewheel event (see https://gyazo.com/03bf86d55006c749cafff0299d67bc50). However, it's no where near perfect and often the scrolling does not fix once a section reaches the top - causing it to skip entire sections.

A function is run on every scroll:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    setTimeout(function (){

        scrollExploration();
        scrollCross();
        scrollConception();

    }, 80);
})
```

The scroll*(); functions basically check to see if one of the sections is within 10 pixels of been at the top and if it is, it will scroll the element to the top and lock the scrolling so the user can scroll down to the next slide and the third slide. Once at the third slide, scrolling unlocks so they can proceed to the next section and this repeats itself really.

The issue is figuring out how to get each section to lock to the top all of the time and not skip (I presume the skipping is currently caused if the user scrolls too fast and the function doesn't run in time to activate the check to see if the section is within the 10 pixel range of the top of the window), and often when on the third slide of a section trying to scroll to the next it either sticks or jumps (presumably because of the function running when scrolling keeping it at the current section).

Comment: Is there any way you could clarify your question? I thought my answer was what you were looking for, but evidently am wrong. Your question is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable scrolling by adding/removing this class as needed

```
body.noscroll {
    position: fixed;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And add/remove the class with `$.addClass()`, `$.removeClass()`, or `$.toggleClass()`